# Curses installed, but cannot be imported (Python)

Tags: python

I have been trying for a while to use the curses module. It says that the module is already installed, but for some reason, I cannot import it.

[cmd says it's already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oSO7.png)

[cannot import the curses module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLupC.png)

Got this error when I tried to install curses through terminal in pycharm:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for curses

Comment: Please, add error message to your question directly. And it doesn't say curses cannot be imported. The problem is with something that curses want to import (in that case, _curses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first image shows that you have installed `curses` on your system python.
In the second image though you are using a virtual environment.

Packages are not shared between the system python and virtual environments (that's the point) so if you want to use `curses` inside the venv you need to install it from inside it.

Just open a terminal in pycharm and you should be automatically put in the venv, then `pip install windows-curses`

Comment: Got this 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for curses

Comment: It is `windows-curses` sorry, will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

When you are using pycharm:

Terminal: `pip install windows - curses` or `pip install windows-curses`